JavaFX ComboBox prevent selection if certain conditions are met
I'm trying to assess the value from ComboBox and based on condition, prevent that change from happening:
ComboBox<String> cb=new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One","Two","Three"));
cb.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs,oldVal,newVal)->loadAll(cb,oldVal,newVal));

private void loadAll(ComboBox cb,String oldVal,String newVal){
   if(newVal.equals("Two")){
        cb.setValue(oldVal);
    }
}

Problem is, loadAll will keep calling itself as cb.setValue(oldVal) is changing the selectedItem again. How to run loadAll before the change has occurred?

The supported approach (that I am aware of) for vetoing changes in selection is to implement a custom selection model. That would avoid changing the selection to one thing and reverting it. Unfortunately that is not a particularly straightforward task. Generally speaking, you should not change a value in a listener for the same value. This question is similar to this recent one (which is about selection in a tree, but the same general principles apply).

An old, unmaintained library, ReactFX, had a feature called inhibeans which were "InhiBeans are extensions of bindings and properties from javafx.beans.* that help prevent redundant invalidations and recalculations.", which seems somewhat similar. However, I don't know if it is the same concept. (This is just an FYI, not a recommendation to use the library or a solution to your issue).

As a quick and dirty hack, you can always just set a boolean flag in the handler and do nothing if it is set, of course.

your approach is suboptimal in several aspects: a) don't change the value of a property you are listening to in the listener (as @James_D already noted) - most of the time you will get away with it and technically you are not doing it here ;) which leads to b) in a listener, NEVER-EVER access a propety that's related to the changed property (aka: not completely orthogonal to the sender c) don't provide the user with options that are not selectable. In your case: implement the condition as an observable, listen to it and reload the combo to always contain valid options

@kleopatra a) The part with providing user with not selectable option is actually simpler version of what I'm actually doing in my project. It doesn't always blocks user from selecting "Two", but only on certain conditions (a boolean flag checks that condition). b) can you please create a small, simple demo of what you're suggesting with your points (a) and (b)? It'll be easier to understand with the code.
